How to use createContext with a hook
So in React, the rules of hooks says that hooks cannot be called outside of functional components.
My predicament: I need to initialize state in my createContext using a hook for the SchedulesProvider. The state is a dynamic date, like two days from the current date. Hooks can't be called outside of functional components. createContext cannot be called within the provider component because it needs to be exported and live outside of the SchedulesProvider.
What I've tried
const utils = useUtils(); //useUtils is a hook from a date library

export const ScheduleContext = createContext({
  scheduleStartDate: utils.date().add(2, "days"), //using the hook here
  ...  
});

My provider is trying to pass the state down like so...
  const { scheduleStartDate } = useContext(ScheduleContext);
    <ScheduleContext.Provider
      value={{
        scheduleStartDate: scheduleStartDate,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ScheduleContext.Provider>

Error I get: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Do you expect the default value to ever be used? In most use cases of context the default value is irrelevant, with the value coming from a provider instead of the default. (By "default value", i mean the object you're passing into createContext)

scheduleStartDate or scheduleEndDate? This is confusing

You probably don't need a default value for your context. The default value is only used if there is no ScheduledContext.Provider higher up the component tree, and you can arrange your components so that never happens.
If you don't need a default value, you can wait until you are rendering the provider to call useUtils. For example:
export const ScheduleContext = createContext(null);
// ...
const MyProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const utils = useUtils();
  return (
    <ScheduleContext.Provider value={{ 
      scheduledStartDate: utils.date().add(2, "days")
    }}>
      {children}
    </ScheduledContext.Provider>
  )
}


With this setup, how would a component wrapped with the provider read the props then? Don't they need to import ScheduleContext and deconstruct props from it to read them? I'm stuck on how child components will be able to read scheduleStartDate.

The child component will import ScheduleContext, then call const { scheduledStartDate } = useContext(ScheduleContext) during rendering.

Thanks! I was way overcomplicating this, and didn't know createContext could just be null like that. Fixed it.

Yeah, when you call useContext(ScheduleContext) react will look up the component tree for the nearest <ScheduleContext.Provider> and return its value. The only way the null (or other default value) would get returned is if no <ScheduleContext.Provider> exists. So as long as you make sure to render a <ScheduleContext.Provider> near the top of your component tree, you'll never need to deal with the default value.

The value you pass to createContext() is more like a fallback for when it's used outside of your context provider hierarchy.
From createContext()

Parameters

defaultValue: The value that you want the context to have when there is no matching context provider in the tree above the component that reads context. If you don’t have any meaningful default value, specify null. The default value is meant as a “last resort” fallback. It is static and never changes over time.


Set the real value with your own provider component instead
const ScheduleContext = createContext({
  scheduleStartDate: new Date(), // or literally anything really
  // ...
});

// define a context provider component
const ScheduleContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { date } = useUtils();
  const scheduleStartDate = date().add(2, 'days');

  return (
    <ScheduleContext.Provider value={{ scheduleStartDate }}>
      {children}
    </ScheduleContext.Provider>
  );
};

// this is also a very handy custom hook for your context
const useSchedule = () => useContext(ScheduleContext);

export { ScheduleContextProvider as default, useSchedule };


I prefer to set a real-ish value for two reasons...

It prevents possible runtime errors like "Cannot read properties of null" or "Cannot destructure property 'x' of 'null'"
If using TypeScript, it allows you to avoid checking for potential nulls every time you want to use your context

